# How to turn off CommandBehavior=SequentialAccess in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, ssms, sql-server-2016

How can we turn off CommandBehavior=SequentialAccess in SQL Server Management Studio so as to avoid this error ?

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Retrieving
>   encrypted column 'DATA' with CommandBehavior=SequentialAccess is not
>   supported.

Background : I am using SQL Server 2016 CTP 3. I have a table with nvarchar(max)columns encrypted using Always Encrypted.

Comment: what is the query you are using,are you trying to access rows non sequentially

Comment: I am using a nornal query. I am not setting anything explicitly. like so : select * from tblsomething

Answer (score 0):

We're currently working on getting this fixed. You can use https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2413024 to track the status of that - but the current target is for the next monthly release of SSMS.

-Charles Gagnon (chgagnon@microsoft.com)

Comment: Thanks Charles. I actually have pointed out this error to Erland Sommarskog who has raised this as bug to microsoft. Check this link out. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/039fae8e-7268-4353-b7b8-f71c2926179c/commandbehaviorsequentialaccess-is-not-supported?forum=SQLServer2016Preview

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed. SSMS now supports decrypting nvarchar(max) columns.

Comment: Maybe add some version number?